# Running a jQuery function on separate classes

Tags: html, jquery

I have some HTML elements, that all have the same markup. Each div does have a unique parent class.

So when I try to write some jQuery to target each element individually it triggers on all instances regardless of whether I specify which class to target. My thinking was by using (this) it would only target stuff inside of the div 'box__wrapper--before'.

Does anyone know where I am going wrong?

```js
$('.box__wrapper--before').each(function() {
  $(this).find('.box__random').insertBefore('.box__item:nth-child(3');
});
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  background: #282828;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 0;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.box__wrapper {
  color: #111;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.box__wrapper:nth-child(odd) {
  background: green;
}

.box__wrapper:nth-child(even) {
  background: blue;
}

.box__container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

.box__flex__wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-left: -60px;
}

.box__item {
  padding-left: 60px;
  flex-basis: 20%;
  max-width: 20%;
}

.box__item span {
  align-items: center;
  border: 4px solid white;
  border-radius: 100px;
  display: flex;
  height: 60px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box__one span,
.box__three span {
  background: #58b2eb;
}

.box__two span,
.box__four span {
  background: #ffa770;
}

.box__random span {
  background: #7fd28c;
}

.prod__cta__msg {
  background: red;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="box__wrapper box__wrapper--before">
  <div class="box__container">
    <div class="box__flex__wrapper">
      <div class="box__item box__one">
        <span>Div One</span>
      </div>

      <div class="box__item box__two">
        <span>Div Two</span>
      </div>

      <div class="box__item box__three">
        <span>Div Three</span>
      </div>

      <div class="box__item box__four">
        <span>Div Four</span>
      </div>

      <div class="box__item box__random">
        <span>Dynamic Div 1</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="box__wrapper box__wrapper--after">
  <div class="box__container">
    <div class="box__flex__wrapper">
      <div class="box__item box__one">
        <span>Div One</span>
      </div>

      <div class="box__item box__two">
        <span>Div Two</span>
      </div>

      <div class="box__item box__three">
        <span>Div Three</span>
      </div>

      <div class="box__item box__four">
        <span>Div Four</span>
      </div>

      <div class="box__item box__random">
        <span>Dynamic Div 2</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Codepen Example: https://codepen.io/nickelse/pen/MWbdvPw

Comment: Not entirely clear what higher level objective is here

Comment: Well, I only want the jQuery to run on any div with the class 'box__wrapper--before' but it targets all divs as the markup is the same inside of both divs. So it finds every instance of 'box__random' not just the ones inside of 'box__wrapper--before'.

Comment: I only see one section with that class. Still not clear. Please provide a proper explanation of full expected behavior and how code shown differs from it

Comment: There are two divs with the exact same markup. One has a parent class of 'box__wrapper--before' and one has 'box__wrapper--after' so I want to only target the markup inside of 'box__wrapper--before' but the jQuery as it is targets everything, so there isn't any specificity.

Comment: OK Can use `$(this).find...` same as the way you find the random class

Comment: There are two divs with the exact same markup. One has a parent class of 'box__wrapper--before' and one has 'box__wrapper--after' so I want to only target the markup inside of 'box__wrapper--before' but the jQuery as it is targets everything, so there isn't any specificity.

Comment: I've updated the snippet to show the "dynamic div" from section 1 is being put in section 1 and section 2 - I assume this is the issue?

Comment: Yeah there is no specificity and I just can't figure out why, so even though I only want to target the children of 'box__wrapper--before' it targets everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with:

```
.insertBefore('.box__item:nth-child(3)')
```

which appends the box_random into all sections.

The `.insertBefore` can take a jquery *object* (not just a string selector) which specifies the insertion point, so you can use `this` to find only the relevant nth-child:

```
$('.box__wrapper--before').each(function() {
  var third = $('.box__item:nth-child(3)', this);
  $(this).find('.box__random').insertBefore(third);
});
```

(variable not required, shown for clarity)

The original could have been written as:

```
$('.box__wrapper--before').each(function() {

  var third = $('.box__item:nth-child(3)');

  $(this).find('.box__random').insertBefore(third);
});
```

where you can see that

```
  var third = $('.box__item:nth-child(3)');
```

selects all items across all parents - so needs that specificity added.

Giving an updated snippet below.  Here the box__random in the 2nd div is not moved because it's not in .box__wrapper--before.

```js
$('.box__wrapper--before').each(function() {
  $(this).find('.box__random').insertBefore($('.box__item:nth-child(3)', this));
});
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  background: #282828;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 0;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.box__wrapper {
  color: #111;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.box__wrapper:nth-child(odd) {
  background: green;
}

.box__wrapper:nth-child(even) {
  background: blue;
}

.box__container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

.box__flex__wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-left: -60px;
}

.box__item {
  padding-left: 60px;
  flex-basis: 20%;
  max-width: 20%;
}

.box__item span {
  align-items: center;
  border: 4px solid white;
  border-radius: 100px;
  display: flex;
  height: 60px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box__one span,
.box__three span {
  background: #58b2eb;
}

.box__two span,
.box__four span {
  background: #ffa770;
}

.box__random span {
  background: #7fd28c;
}

.prod__cta__msg {
  background: red;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="box__wrapper box__wrapper--before">
  <div class="box__container">
    <div class="box__flex__wrapper">
      <div class="box__item box__one">
        <span>Div One</span>
      </div>

      <div class="box__item box__two">
        <span>Div Two</span>
      </div>

      <div class="box__item box__three">
        <span>Div Three</span>
      </div>

      <div class="box__item box__four">
        <span>Div Four</span>
      </div>

      <div class="box__item box__random">
        <span>Dynamic Div 1</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="box__wrapper box__wrapper--after">
  <div class="box__container">
    <div class="box__flex__wrapper">
      <div class="box__item box__one">
        <span>Div One</span>
      </div>

      <div class="box__item box__two">
        <span>Div Two</span>
      </div>

      <div class="box__item box__three">
        <span>Div Three</span>
      </div>

      <div class="box__item box__four">
        <span>Div Four</span>
      </div>

      <div class="box__item box__random">
        <span>Dynamic Div 2</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```